# Delete custom macOS keyboard layout

Tags: macos, keyboard, settings, customization

I installed several custom keyboard layouts in macOS and would like to delete some. Note: I don't want to simply disable them but remove them completely. However, in the input source menu there is no way to completely remove a keyboard layout (apart from disabling it).

Answer (score 2):

Custom layouts are stored in `/Library/Keyboard Layouts` directory (Systemwide) or `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts` directory (User only).  Go there and delete them.

To get to a specific directory, in Finder press <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and copy paste one of the paths above and press <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>.